# PyInstaller Generated EXE failed to run

Tags: python, windows, pyqt, exe, pyinstaller

I'm having a problem with running PyInstaller generated .EXE file. The .EXE file generated, but once I run the .EXE it says following.

[image]

The following is the command that I run to generate the .EXE file.

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed milktest.py
```

I was searching and doing all the solutions given on different forums and posts, but still no luck.

**EDIT:
Follwing is my code**

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys


class MilkTest(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)

        self.FAT_MAX = 30.0
        self.PROTEIN_MAX = 20.0
        self.SNF_MAX = 10.0
        self.RESAZURIN_MAX = 10.0
        self.ACIDITY_MAX = 10.0
        self.LACTOMETER_MAX = 20.0

        self.REJECTED = "REJECTED"
        self.ACCEPTED = "ACCEPTED"

        self.HIGHEST_PRICE = "HIGHEST PRICE"
        self.SECOND_PRICE = "SECOND PRICE"
        self.THIRD_PRICE = "THIRD PRICE"
        self.REJECTED_PRICE = "NO CATEGORY"

        layout = QGridLayout()

        l_name = QLabel("Name")
        l_date = QLabel("Date")
        l_fat = QLabel("Fat")
        l_protein = QLabel("Protein")
        l_snf = QLabel("SNF")
        l_temperature = QLabel("Temperature(C)")
        l_alcohol_test = QLabel("Alcohol")
        l_resazurin = QLabel("Resazurin")
        l_acidity = QLabel("Acidity")
        l_inhibitor_test = QLabel("Inhibitor Test")
        l_lactometer = QLabel("Lactometer")
        l_points = QLabel("Points")
        l_status = QLabel("Status")
        self.l_gained_status = QLabel("N/A")
        l_price = QLabel("Price Category")
        self.l_gained_price = QLabel("N/A")

        self.le_name = QLineEdit()

        self.de_date = QDateEdit()
        self.de_date.setCalendarPopup(True)
        self.de_date.setDate(QDate.currentDate())

        self.dsb_fat = QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.dsb_fat.setMinimum(0.0)
        self.dsb_fat.setMaximum(30.0)
        self.dsb_fat.setSingleStep(0.10)

        self.dsb_protein = QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.dsb_protein.setMinimum(0.0)
        self.dsb_protein.setMaximum(30.0)
        self.dsb_protein.setSingleStep(0.10)

        self.dsb_snf = QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.dsb_snf.setMinimum(0.0)
        self.dsb_snf.setMaximum(30.0)
        self.dsb_snf.setSingleStep(0.10)

        self.dsb_temperature = QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.dsb_temperature.setMinimum(0.0)
        self.dsb_temperature.setMaximum(100.0)
        self.dsb_temperature.setSingleStep(0.10)

        # bg_alcohol_test = QButtonGroup()
        # rb_negative = QRadioButton("Negative")
        # rb_positive = QRadioButton("Positive")
        # bg_alcohol_test.addButton(rb_negative)
        # bg_alcohol_test.addButton(rb_positive)

        self.cb_alcohol_test = QComboBox()
        self.cb_alcohol_test.addItems(["Negative", "Positive"])

        self.cb_resazurin = QComboBox()
        self.cb_resazurin.addItems(["Blue", "Light Blue", "Purple", "Purple Pink", "Light Pink", "Pink", "White"])

        self.dsb_acidity = QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.dsb_acidity.setMinimum(0.0)
        self.dsb_acidity.setMaximum(10.0)
        self.dsb_acidity.setSingleStep(0.10)

        self.cb_inhibitor_test = QComboBox()
        self.cb_inhibitor_test.addItems(["Negative", "Positive"])

        self.dsb_lactometer = QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.dsb_lactometer.setMinimum(0.0)
        self.dsb_lactometer.setMaximum(100.0)
        self.dsb_lactometer.setSingleStep(0.10)

        self.pb_close = QPushButton("Close")
        self.pb_reset = QPushButton("Reset")
        self.pb_calculate = QPushButton("Calculate")

        self.lcdn_points = QLCDNumber()
        self.lcdn_points.setSmallDecimalPoint(True)
        self.lcdn_points.display(0)
        palette = self.lcdn_points.palette()

        # foreground color
        palette.setColor(palette.WindowText, QColor(32, 32, 32))
        # background color
        palette.setColor(palette.Background, QColor(32, 32, 32))
        # "light" border
        palette.setColor(palette.Light, QColor(32, 32, 32))
        # "dark" border
        palette.setColor(palette.Dark, QColor(153, 153, 255))

        # set the palette
        self.lcdn_points.setPalette(palette)

        layout.addWidget(l_name, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.le_name, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(l_date, 0, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.de_date, 0, 3)

        layout.addWidget(l_fat, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.dsb_fat, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(l_protein, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.dsb_protein, 1, 3)

        layout.addWidget(l_snf, 2, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.dsb_snf, 2, 1)
        layout.addWidget(l_temperature, 2, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.dsb_temperature, 2, 3)

        layout.addWidget(l_alcohol_test, 3, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.cb_alcohol_test, 3, 1)
        layout.addWidget(l_resazurin, 3, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.cb_resazurin, 3, 3)

        layout.addWidget(l_acidity, 4, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.dsb_acidity, 4, 1)
        layout.addWidget(l_inhibitor_test, 4, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.cb_inhibitor_test, 4, 3)

        layout.addWidget(l_lactometer, 5, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.dsb_lactometer, 5, 1)
        layout.addWidget(l_points, 5, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.lcdn_points, 5, 3)

        layout.addWidget(l_status, 6, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.l_gained_status, 6, 1)
        layout.addWidget(l_price, 6, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.l_gained_price, 6, 3)

        layout.addWidget(self.pb_close, 7, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.pb_reset, 7, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.pb_calculate, 7, 3)

        self.pb_close.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.pb_reset.clicked.connect(self.reset)
        self.pb_calculate.clicked.connect(self.calculate)

        app_icon = QIcon()
        app_icon.addFile('flask512.png', QSize(512, 512))
        app_icon.addFile('flask256.png', QSize(256, 256))
        app_icon.addFile('flask128.png', QSize(128, 128))
        app_icon.addFile('flask64.png', QSize(64, 64))
        app_icon.addFile('flask32.png', QSize(32, 32))
        app_icon.addFile('flask24.png', QSize(24, 24))
        app_icon.addFile('flask16.png', QSize(16, 16))
        self.setWindowIcon(app_icon)
        self.setWindowTitle("MILK TEST")

        self.setLayout(layout)


    def reset(self):
        self.le_name.setText("")
        self.de_date.setDate(QDate.currentDate())
        self.dsb_fat.setValue(0.0)
        self.dsb_protein.setValue(0.0)
        self.dsb_snf.setValue(0.0)
        self.dsb_temperature.setValue(0.0)
        self.cb_alcohol_test.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.cb_resazurin.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.dsb_acidity.setValue(0.0)
        self.cb_inhibitor_test.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.dsb_lactometer.setValue(0.0)
        self.lcdn_points.display(0)


    def calculate(self):
        fat_points = 0.0
        protein_points = 0.0
        snf_points = 0.0
        resazurin_points = 0.0
        acidity_points = 0.0
        lactometer_points = 0.0
        points_gained = 0.0

        points_percentage = 0

        fat_val = self.dsb_fat.value()
        protein_val = self.dsb_protein.value()
        snf_val = self.dsb_snf.value()
        resazurin_index = self.cb_resazurin.currentIndex()
        acidity_val = self.dsb_acidity.value()
        lactometer_val = self.dsb_lactometer.value()

        TOTAL_MAX = (
            self.FAT_MAX + self.PROTEIN_MAX + self.SNF_MAX + self.RESAZURIN_MAX + self.ACIDITY_MAX + self.LACTOMETER_MAX)

        if (fat_val >= 3.7):
            fat_points = 30.0
        elif (fat_val <= 3.6 and fat_val >= 3.3):
            fat_points = 20.0
        elif (fat_val <= 3.2 and fat_val >= 2.8):
            fat_points = 10.0
        else:
            fat_points = 5.0

        if (protein_val >= 3.2):
            protein_points = 20.0
        elif (protein_val <= 3.1 and protein_val >= 2.8):
            protein_points = 10.0
        else:
            protein_points = 5.0

        if (snf_val >= 8.7):
            snf_points = 10.0
        elif (snf_val <= 8.6 and snf_val >= 7.9):
            snf_points = 5.0
        else:
            snf_points = 0.0

        if (resazurin_index == 0 or resazurin_index == 1 or resazurin_index == 2):
            resazurin_points = 10.0
        elif (resazurin_index == 3 or resazurin_index == 4):
            resazurin_points = 5.0
        else:
            resazurin_points = 0.0

        if (acidity_val >= 0.1 and acidity_val <= 0.26):
            acidity_points = 10.0
        else:
            acidity_points = 0.0

        if (lactometer_val >= 26.0 and lactometer_val <= 32.0):
            lactometer_points = 20.0
        else:
            lactometer_points = 0.0

        points_gained = (fat_points + protein_points + snf_points + resazurin_points + acidity_points + lactometer_points)

        points_percentage = int((points_gained * 100) / TOTAL_MAX)

        self.lcdn_points.display(points_percentage)

        if(points_percentage >= 35 and self.cb_alcohol_test.currentIndex() == 0 and (self.cb_resazurin.currentIndex() == 0 or self.cb_resazurin.currentIndex() == 1 or self.cb_resazurin.currentIndex() == 2 or self.cb_resazurin.currentIndex() == 3 or self.cb_resazurin.currentIndex() == 4) and self.cb_inhibitor_test.currentIndex() == 0 and (self.dsb_temperature.value() >= 15 and self.dsb_temperature.value() <= 20)):
            self.l_gained_status.setText(self.ACCEPTED)
        else:
            self.l_gained_status.setText(self.REJECTED)

        if (points_percentage >= 80):
            self.l_gained_price.setText(self.HIGHEST_PRICE)
        elif (points_percentage < 80 and points_percentage >= 60):
            self.l_gained_price.setText(self.SECOND_PRICE)
        elif (points_percentage < 60 and points_percentage >= 45):
            self.l_gained_price.setText(self.THIRD_PRICE)
        elif (points_percentage < 45 and points_percentage >= 35):
            self.l_gained_price.setText(self.FOURTH_PRICE)
        else:
            self.l_gained_price.setText(self.REJECTED_PRICE)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
dialog = MilkTest()
dialog.show()
app.exec_()
```

Please can anyone help me?.

Thank you very much

Comment: Look in the folder where you have installed pyqt and you will find the folder platform, copy that folder to the side of your executable.

Comment: You mean where my .exe exists ? Did that, still not working. Thank you very much for you quick response. I'm in a big trouble as this is a University assignment. Please help !! :-(

Comment: Look in the folder where you have installed python, in that place there should be a folder called lib, inside it site-packages, and inside it a folder called pyqtX

Comment: Still the same result :-(

Comment: You could explain what you have done, if you do not give us information we will not be able to help you. I could help you through teamviewer.

Comment: attached my code. Can you please look at it? . Please let me know what else I have to provide. Thank you very much !

Comment: I have not asked for the code, what happens is that an .exe application needs the compiled libraries, ie .dlls, usually when you run through python, this is responsible for doing all the necessary searches, but as You convert them to .exe, you are in charge of providing those .dlls, pyqt is based on qt, it is actually a translation of qt for python, qt needs a certain project structure. I have offered you my help to find the necessary files on your pc, but I can only do it through teamviewer, please confirm me if you accept my help.

Comment: Yes. Please help !